# how to add productId to SOAP v2 request

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

Is there a way to add productId to soap request?

My soap request is missing productId argument. I can't change source of request. But I was thinking to add it from api extension module?

Any suggestions ?

```
[...]
<data xmlns="">
        <complexObjectArray>
          <sku>0110000001249</sku>
          <productData>
[...]
```

should be

```
[...]
<data xmlns="">
        <complexObjectArray>
          <sku>0110000001249</sku>
          <productId>10914</productId>
          <productData>
[...]
```

Many Thanks